# is there a built in way to create a list of consecutive integers?

Tags: netlogo

I'm looking for a built in way to create a list of consecutive integers: 1 to n.
IE: `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`

Does it exist? Currently I'm manually creating the list, which is wasteful.

Manual method: `let group-list [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should add the solution as an answer and then mark it correct when you can so that this question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the answer:**

`show n-values 9 [?]` will display `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`
`show n-values 9 [? + 1]` will display `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`